# Spectral theorem for diagonlizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a diagonalizable matrix $\textbf A_{n \times n}$ with spectrum $σ(\textbf A)=\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2,..., \lambda_k\}$ we have matrices $\{ \textbf G_1, \textbf G_2,..., \textbf G_k \}$ such that:

$
\textbf A=\lambda_1 \textbf G_1+\lambda_2 \textbf G_2+...+\lambda_k \textbf G_k,
$

where each $\textbf G_i$ is the projector onto $N(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)$ along $R(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)$.

Since every projector is associated with complementary subspaces - its range and its null space, it must be that $N(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)$ and $R(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)$ are complementary.

How to prove that $N(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)$ and $R(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)$ are complementary subspaces, i.e. $N(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I) \cap R(\textbf A-\lambda_i \textbf I)=\textbf 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spaces are not disjoint, then there is a vector $x$ such that $(A-\lambda I)x\neq 0$, but $(A-\lambda I)^2 x =0$. Show that $x$ is linearly independent to all eigenvectors associated with that same $\lambda$. Show moreover that $x$ is linearly independent to all other eigenvectors.

Once the above is shown, we conclude that since the vector $x$ lies outside the span of the eigenvectors of $A$, there is no basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, which is to say that $A$ fails to be diagonalizable.

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarification on any of those steps.  I recommend you start by trying to think through them on your own first, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got that $x$ is linearly independent to all eigenvectors associated with the same $\lambda$ since $x$ shouldn't be in the null-space of $\textbf A - \lambda \textbf I$. The last part I read as that since one n-dimensional vector couldn't be expressed as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $A$ so there is no n linearly independent eigenvectors and so $A$ cannot be diagonalizable. The only thing that I can't conclude is that $x$ is linearly independent to all other eigenvectors. Could you give me hint about it?

Comment: Write a linear combination of the other eigenvectors as 
$$
x = a_1x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n
$$
where the $x_i$ are (linearly independent) eigenvectors, each with associated eigenvalue $\lambda_i \neq \lambda$.  Show that we can only have $(A - \lambda I)^2 x = 0$ if $a_i = 0$ for each $i$.  So, this $x$ cannot possibly be a non-zero $x$ satisfying $(A - \lambda I)^2 x = 0$.

Comment: I reached the point $a_1(\textbf A-\lambda \textbf I)^2 \textbf x_1+a_2(\textbf A-\lambda \textbf I)^2 \textbf x_2+...+a_n(\textbf A-\lambda \textbf I)^2 \textbf x_n=\textbf 0$ and can't go further so please help me with that prove!

Comment: The $x_i$ are eigenvectors!!!

Comment: @Pekov it just multiplies each eigenvector by a scalar

Comment: @Pekov $$
(A - \lambda I)x_i = Ax_i - \lambda x_i = (\lambda_i - \lambda)x_i
$$  Similarly, $(A - \lambda I)^2 x_i = (\lambda _i - \lambda )^2 x_i$.